# Critical issue in sending alerts in Tradingview (pine script)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, algorithmic-trading, tradingview-api

I use this code to retrieve data from several symbols so that when certain conditions are established, I will be notified by an alert.
However, the problem is that in 90% of the time, it sends two simultaneous and repeated alerts for that symbol.
This is a big problem because when we connect the alert to the trading platform through a webhook, since two alerts are sent at the same time, two orders are opened at the same time, one of which is actually added.
Is there a problem in the following code or is it a problem from the Tradingview side?
Is there a solution for that?

```
//@version=5
indicator('Test', overlay=true)
fastLength = input(9)
slowLength = input(18)
price = close
mafast = ta.sma(price, fastLength)
maslow = ta.sma(price, slowLength)

//conditions
buysignal = (ta.crossover(mafast, maslow))
sellsignal = (ta.crossunder(mafast, maslow))

// check any condition you needed to fire
checkForAlert()=>
    alertMsg = ""

    // check for highest high
    if buysignal
        alertMsg += str.format("buy,{0},risk=1", syminfo.ticker)

    // check for lowest low
    if sellsignal
        alertMsg += str.format("sell,{0},risk=1", syminfo.ticker)


    // any other checks needed

    alertMsg

fireAlert(ticker, freq = alert.freq_once_per_bar)=>
    msg = request.security(ticker, timeframe.period, checkForAlert())
    if str.length(msg) > 0
        alert(msg, freq)

fireAlert("OANDA:GBPJPY")
fireAlert("OANDA:GBPUSD")
fireAlert("OANDA:GBPCAD")
fireAlert("OANDA:EURGBP")
fireAlert("OANDA:EURJPY")
// more symbols here ... max 40
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. when I added the built-in `timenow` function in PineScript to each alert message, I could see the same timestamp values with the alert messages.

Consequently, I had to modify the script or include a specific ID to categorize and differentiate each alert message

I have implemented both solutions, but I am utilizing Interactive Brokers instead of OANDA.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34433095)